ASP.Net Core views failing on Android MAUI with Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CompilationFailedException
I'm trying to get ASP.NET Core running on Android using a MAUI app. Until now I was able to successfully integrate ASP.NET including controllers using the https://github.com/JamesNK/aspnetcore-maui project. Basically the hack is to add the Asp.Net.Core dlls as direct references, I just had to replace the SDK folder to the latest version:
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MauiApp.Web\MauiApp.Web.csproj" />
    <Reference Include="C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\8.0.3\*.dll" Exclude="C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\8.0.3\aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll">
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

But I'm lost to get the views (*.cshtml) running. I already followed CompilationFailedException during runtime compilation of Razor from AspNetCore TestHost but without success, this is how my startup code looks like for the razor part:
var assembly = callingAssembly;

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddApplicationPart(typeof(WebAppHostProgram).Assembly);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddApplicationPart(assembly).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(
    options =>
    {
        // important to clear because some of them are null
        options.FileProviders.Clear();

        // resolve views as embedded resources
        options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(HomeController).Assembly));
    });

After calling the index controller action, it starts throwing the folling errors:
[DOTNET] info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[105]
[DOTNET]       Executed action MauiApp.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MauiApp.Web) in 2156.7141ms
[0:] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MauiApp.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MauiApp.Web) in 2156.7141ms
[DOTNET] info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
[DOTNET]       Executed endpoint 'MauiApp.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MauiApp.Web)'
[0:] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint 'MauiApp.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MauiApp.Web)'
[DOTNET] fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
[DOTNET]       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
[DOTNET]       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
[DOTNET]       lhzz1lae.ayr(4,20): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
[DOTNET]       lhzz1lae.ayr(4,82): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
[DOTNET]       lhzz1lae.ayr(4,120): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported

I figured, the *.deps.json file was missing in the root folder. I tried already to load that as an android asset and copy as a static file to the dlls-folder, but still, same issue.
